# Is it possible to use extension methods which are added at implementation file rather than interface file in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

This is **header file/Interface file(className.h).**
Here **printSomething** method is declared as an extension. And I'll call it later in main.m

*extension.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface extension_class : NSObject

@end


@interface extension_class ()       // This is the external method which is added using extension
- (void) printSomething;
@end
```

This is the **Implementation file(className.m).** Here **printSomething** method is defined.

*extension.m*

```
        #import "extensions.h"
        
        @implementation extension_class
        
        - (void) printSomething
        {
            NSLog(@"I'm the method defined inside extension class but declared by using extensions");
        }
        @end
```

So far everything works fine. Now My question is simple why can't I access that **printSomething** method if I declare(until now declaration and definition was not done in same file) it in implementation file. As in the below code snippet? (Please compare and observe the changes among above two .h and .m files with below ones to get my point)

*extension.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        
        @interface extension_class : NSObject
        
        @end
```

*extension.m*

```
    #import "extensions.h"
    
    @interface extension_class ()       // This is the external method which is added using extension
    - (void) printSomething;
    @end

    @implementation extension_class
    - (void) printSomething
    {
        NSLog(@"I'm the method defined inside extension class but declared by using extensions");
    }
    @end
```

This is main method which is common in both cases.

*main.m*

```
#import "extensions.h"
int main()
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        extension_class *object = [[extension_class alloc]init];
        [object printSomething];
    }
    return 'O';
}
```

So what is point in having extensions in objective C if it doesn't allow us to add methods anywhere we like? or Is there any other method to achieve what I said above?

Comment: Hi - not entirely clear what you are struggling with. But if you put the ```interface``` in the .m file it means that it is sort of private. If you put it in the .h file it is visible to all. Apart from that there is little difference between the two.

Comment: @skaak , It's pretty simple. Is there any way to add extensions at implementation(.m) file or main method or anywhere except interface(.h) file.

Comment: Here's something that may help. The header file contains what you want to publish to the outside world. Everything you put in there is visible to others, the same as with C. You use the header specifically to exposure functions in C or class methods in Objective-C. In C and Objective-C, the header is where you put known function definitions, global variables, class definitions and class methods and so on. The compiler reads the header file to know what it will find in the compiled code later on.

Comment: There may be plenty other functions and methods that you do not put in the header but these won't be visible to others. You can add methods in your implementation but if you want others to use them you have to add them to the header as well. Then you need to implement these in an implementation somewhere, typically .c for C and .m for Objective-C. But there are several options. You can override methods later or use generics and so on if that is what you are after. There are also protocols and extensions in Objective-C that you use to provide the definition without the implementation.

Comment: My question is entirely about your last sentence of third comment. It's purely exploring the concept called 'extensions' in objective-C. But there is a problem with this feature. The main advantage of extensions should be to be able to add any methods(unexpected methods) requires at time which are not specified anywhere in header file or any classes header files holds(There is a difference between header file and classes it holds). But it is not allowing me to add explicit methods at main method. If I understood extensions correctly, it should allow me to add new methods by including header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're free to define extensions in the .m file. This is incredibly common. Those extensions won't generally be known to importers of the .h file, so they won't easily be callable from other files. That's a good thing. It lets us make "private" extensions, which is very useful and common.

They're not really private. Anything can call anything in ObjC. Outside callers just won't know about the method. But they can declare the method themselves as a category (note the text inside the parentheses) and call it:

*OtherClass.m*

```
#import "ExtensionClass.h"

@interface ExtensionClass (ThingsIKnowYouHave)
- (void) printSomething;
@end

...

[extensionClass printSomething];
```

Or they could of course just call it directly without declaring it (though this can cause ARC problems, so avoid this in modern ObjC):

```
[(id)extensionClass printSomething];
```

Or they could call it as a selector (again, this can cause ARC problems; so using the category is best):

```
[extensionClass performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(@"printSomething")];
```

There's really not much point to creating extensions in the header file (i.e. "public" extensions). If it's in the header file, you might as well just put it in the interface. The most common use of extensions (basically why they were invented), is so you can define methods inside the implementation file.

Extensions shouldn't be confused with categories, where there is text inside the parentheses. These were created to help organize large classes, and later were used for "informal protocols" before `@optional` was added. Extensions can add methods directly to the base class. Category interfaces just say "this method might exist." Extension interfaces are formal continuations of the primary interface (the compiler requires that they be implemented).

For more on categories and extensions, see [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1) in the Programming with Objective-C guide. See also [Defining Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW1) in the same guide, which may clear up some confusion I believe you have about header files and interfaces.